# TypeError in Real Time Sign Language Detection Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm trying to implement a python program which makes hand gesture recognitions and detects unwanted gestures such as profanity. I watched a tutorial on youtube about "Real Time Sign Language Detection with Tensorflow Object Detection and Python" [Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDXdlXlaCco&t=1280s) and did whatever the instructor did. At some point the youtuber guy executes a command in jupyter notebook.

The command is:

```
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x {IMAGE_PATH + '/train'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/train.record'}
!python {SCRIPTS_PATH + '/generate_tfrecord.py'} -x{IMAGE_PATH + '/test'} -l {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/label_map.pbtxt'} -o {ANNOTATION_PATH + '/test.record'}
```

When I run this command I get an error which I cant fix for 2 days. Please help me to solve it.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(filename: str, buffer_size: int, token: tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.TransactionToken = None)

Invoked with: item {
  name: "bad_sign_1"
  id: 1
}
item {
  name: "bad_sign_2"
  id: 2
}
, 524288
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Tensorflow/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 62, in <module>
    label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 164, in get_label_map_dict
    label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 133, in load_labelmap
    label_map_string = fid.read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 80, in _preread_check
    compat.path_to_str(self.__name), 1024 * 512)
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(filename: str, buffer_size: int, token: tensorflow.python.lib.io._pywrap_file_io.TransactionToken = None)

Invoked with: item {
  name: "bad_sign_1"
  id: 1
}
item {
  name: "bad_sign_2"
  id: 2
}
, 524288
```

I tried to put the code files but they are too long and exceed the character limits. I load the project instead.

Project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZwSbIbFV2hEzNc3EXYpuPJUGeWZWN4xS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)
```

in your tfrecord generate script with

```
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(args.labels_path)
```